May Jews recite a hesped for a Talmid chacham on Isru chag
According to Halacha, eulogies are not allowed to be held on Isru Chag of Shavuot, and there is a very strong minhag for the other Isru Chags. My question is, does this also apply to a hesped for a Talmid Chacham?

Source for your assertions which form the basis for your question? And you couldn't Google this and b find this url which directly answers it, regarding a talmid chacham? https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/chapter-7-eulogy-hesped/
